# TUM RGBD SLAM dataset file format inconsistency?

Tags: slam, monocular

I'm looking at the [TUM dataset](https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/download) and wonder why the depth images and the file formats appear to be inconsistent. According to the [file formats](https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/file_formats):

> The depth images are scaled by a
>   factor of 5000, i.e., a pixel value of
>   5000 in the depth image corresponds to
>   a distance of 1 meter from the camera,
>   10000 to 2 meter distance, etc. A
>   pixel value of 0 means missing
>   value/no data.

However, the pixels in the background appear to be darker than those in the foreground. By the file formats, the background pixels should have higher values than those in the foreground. How come they are darker?

[image]

Comment: perhaps they represent "no data"

Comment: @jsotola I think you're right! Thanks.

Comment: you even quoted the answer in your question: "A pixel value of 0 means missing value/no data."